# Build error when trying to include CorePlot as static library

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, core-plot, build-error

I've been given the responsibility of fixing some bugs on a project. The project uses CorePlot. When I copied the project to my computer and tried to build it I got the following error:

> error: There is no SDK with specified name or path '/Users/name/Library/SDKs/CorePlotSDK/iphonesimulator.sdk'

I think the original programmer had included CorePlot as a dependent project. I'm attempting to use a static library install as explained in the Google Code page of the [CorePlot project](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications) but I get the above error. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Core Plot SDK is no longer supported. Remove it from the "Additional SDKs" build setting for the project and the app target. You should also remove the `-lCorePlot` linker flag.